# Overriding elements of an array in "each" loop

Tags: ruby, overriding, each

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a.each do |x| x+=10 end
```

After this operation array a is still `[1, 2, 3]`. How to convert it into `[11, 12, 13]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two general classes of solutions:

***Imperative object-mutating code***

```
a.map! { |x| x + 10 }
```

***An almost [functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) solution***

```
a = a.map { |x| x + 10 }
```

Both techniques have their place.

Comment: The first one is given by dmarkow, and the second one is given by Ryanmt.

Comment: I was definitely late, and this is really not a good example of the imperative vs functional divide, but I did try to add some value. I never answer questions with reasonable replies, but sometimes I start on an unanswered question and get interrupted or work too slowly, that's for sure.

Comment: Do you feel uneasy about using `a` for both the original and the new array?

Comment: Heh, yes, *"semi-functional".*

Answer (score 7):

Use the `collect!` method:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a.collect!{ |x| x + 10 }
```

Comment: `map!` is 4 signs shorter! :D

Answer (score 2):

I like the aliased name "map" myself.  It has less characters.

The difference with these methods as compared to what you've done is two fold.  One is that you have to use a method that modifies the initial array (typically these are the bang methods, or the methods which have a name ending in a ! (map!, collect!, ...)  The second thing is that a.each is the method typically used for just going through the array to use the individual elements.  Map or Collect methods return an array containing a return from each iteration of the block.

Hence, you could have done the following:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = []
a.each do |x| 
   b << x+10
end
```

or you could use the map or collect method as demonstrated by dmarko or as here:

```
a = [1,2,3]
a = a.map {|x| x+10}
```